# Handling generalization/specialization in CakePHP?

Tags: sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I apologize if I'm using the wrong terms here (please feel free to correct my post or comment).  Obviously the SQL isn't super complicated outside of CakePHP, but I'd like learn the correct way to handle this situation with CakePHP.

---

**The situation**

I have a generalization/specialization database set up.  I've simplified it here (and changed the names to make it clear:

```
 Humans: id, first_name, last_name, hobby
 Parents: id, human_id, job
 Students: id, human_id, grade
```

---

**Questions:**

1. My associations should be `parents has_one humans`, `students has_one humans`, `humans has_one parents` and `humans has_one students`, correct?  I always struggle with associations.
2. How do I then search one specialization model for data contained in the general model using Cake's conventions?  So, for example, how would I search only my students for a particular first name?

Comment: 1. Unless the tables have a unique index on each field named human_id, then each human can have many parents, as well as many students. I've done subclassing like this by making the primary key (non-identity or autoincrement) the foreign key to the superclass table. Then no need for extra indexes, or unintended effects from a potential 1:N relationship.

Comment: See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html & http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html it's all explained there in great detail.

Comment: @burzum: The chapters that you have referenced do not say anything about subtyping!?

Comment: What is subtyping for you in this context?

Comment: @JaazCole - I believe (though I could be mistaken) that the convention for cake is to always give it an ID field, even if it normally wouldn't be necessary.  Is that wrong?

Comment: @burzum - I've read those sections... while my first question is addressed (and I know that, I'm just asking for confirmation that I've understood it correctly), I don't believe my second question is addressed at all, nor the general idea behind my question (which is asking how to properly handle generalization/specialization in cake).  Is the a particular section you had in mind that I missed?

Comment: @burzum: subtyping is about defining subtypes (specialization) and supertypes (generalization), and the implied inheritance of properties and methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to question 1:**

Your naming is correct (beside that "parents" leads to the modelname "Parent", which is not allowed, because it's a PHP keyword).

The following associations should be sufficient:
Parent belongsTo Human, Student belongsTo Human

**Answer to question 2:**

Try this in your Student controller (after you created the association in the student model):

```
$this->Student->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Human.first_name' => 'AnyFirstNameYouWant')));
```

Otherwise have a look at:

CakePHP doesnt support Multi-Table-/Joined-Table-Inheritance.

You could try the Containable-Behavior:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Or the behaviour made for model inheritance with Multi-Table-Inheritance support:

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/santino83/2011/02/19/behavior_for_model_inheritance_the_missing_feature

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!  I now recall that I intentionally changed the "Parents" table to be "Parents_Guardians" or something to that effect because of that exact error, and then changed it back a few days ago when I was reworking my database.  Thank you so much for the reminder.  So the human to parent/student association is unnecessary?
As for question 2, I did come across the containable behavior, but was unable to work out how to put it to use for a situation like this... you don't by chance know of an example I could look at?  I saw the other behavior you mention, but it's out of date.

Comment: I should ask, is there a "cake" way to handle this, since Cake doesn't support a setup like this?  Perhaps I should just push it all into the human table and have some null values?

Comment: I think there isn't a cake way, but you could think of it in a usual model and association way and not in terms of generalization/specialization. so there could be only the associations from parent and student to human in only one direction. But the easiest way is, as you suggested, to use single table inheritance. Maybe I find some time to setup your situation in a test-environment and try to solve it with the containable-behavior.

Comment: I created the human, student and parent models (with associations), controllers and views. 

And to match your request (i.e. find student by its first_name), I tried the following and it works (without the usage of any behaviour):
`debug($this->Student->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Human.first_name' => 'John'))));`

Comment: Are you kidding me?!  It was that easy?  Wow, I feel like a dunce.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to your question 1:

First notice that since you describe a relational database schema, and not a UML class diagram, you do not deal with "associations", but rather with foreign key dependencies.

As suggested in the comment by Jaaz Cole, for expressing a table hierarchy where `humans` (better call it `people` as the plural of `person`) is a supertable of both `parents`and `students`, you normally declare the primary keys of the subtables to be foreign keys referencing the supertable. So, you should drop your `human_id` columns.

Comment: Is that true even within cakephp?  I understood (perhaps wrongly) that cake conventions required separate fields for the ID and foreign key?

Comment: I'm not yet very familiar with CakePHP. The conventions you mention certainly apply to associations, but do they also apply to subtyping?

Comment: That's why I ask, lol.  I suspect I'm going to need a cake expert rather than a sql expert on this one... my fault for tagging the way I did.